# Failed to resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.3

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to `Android-studio` and `Firebase`.

I am trying to add `Firebase` UI dependency to my android project and ultimately plan to use `FireBase` facebook authentication UI.

But I get this message every time I try to sync.

```
Failed to resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.3
```

I checked [this link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) to see the versions but everything looked fine.

This is how my `build.gradle` looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rohintak.firebasepractice"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // FirebaseUI Database only
    //compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.5.3'
    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    //compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.5.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.3'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Hmm, have "Work Offline" enabled in your Android Studio settings?

Comment: No, it is unchecked, other dependencies were added without any issue except this one.

Answer (score 0):

You're including different versions of the Firebase SDK and FirebaseUI. That won't work.

Cleaned up dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.5.3'
}
```

Comment: I am using the same versions you mentioned here, by mistake I typed 0.4.4, I was trying 0.5.3 for Firebase UI.
And According to the Github link I mentioned in my post even 0.4.4 should work with SDK version 9.4.0.  (I pasted your versions anyways but still no luck)

Comment: @RohinTak same error still? Have you tried clean build? Check if your AS can access internet.

Comment: I feel there is some issue with Android studio and internet connection.
I will update here once I try, Thanks everyone

Comment: It was a network problem after all. Something was wrong with my office network that was stopping android studio from connecting.
Worked on home Wifi.
Thanks everybody for your time.